# Why does $\lambda (e^x - 1) = x$ have two solutions for $\lambda > 1$?

Tags: solution-verification

Apparently $\lambda (e^x - 1) = x$ has two solutions for $\lambda > 1$.

My textbook is kind of handwaving and saying that this is true without explaining. Can somebody prove this for me or show me why this is true? I understand why $x=0$ is always a solution, but why will a new solution appear for $\lambda > 1$? I see that it is true when I graph it, but I'd like a more algebraic proof for it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\lambda(e^x - 1) = x \iff\\
e^x - \frac 1\lambda x - 1 = 0
$$
It's unfortunately impossible to "solve" for the roots of this equation using algebra.  However, a little calculus goes a long way.  Define
$$
f(x) = e^x - \frac 1\lambda x - 1 = 0
$$
We can find the critical points of this function by setting the derivative equal to $0$:
$$
f'(x) = e^x - \frac 1\lambda = 0 \implies\\x = -\log(\lambda)
$$
After verifying that the critical point at $x = -\log(\lambda)$ is necessarily a **global minimum** and that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = \infty$, we note that
$$
f(-\log(\lambda)) = \frac 1\lambda - \frac{\log \lambda}{\lambda} - 1 = \frac{1-\lambda - \log(\lambda)}{\lambda}
$$
Now, if $\lambda > 1$, then this minimum of $f$ is **negative**.  This implies that as $x$ increases, the graph for $f(x)$ must "start" positive, **cross the $x$-axis** to reach its minimum, and then increase towards $+\infty$, **crossing the $x$-axis** once more.

That is, $f(x) = 0$ must have two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, function $$f(x)=\lambda (e^x - 1) - x$$ is equal to $0$ if $x=0$ for any value of $\lambda$. As, said in other answers, the derivative $$f'(x)=\lambda  e^x-1$$ cancels at $x=\log \left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)$ and at this point $$f(x)=-\lambda -\log \left(\frac{1}{\lambda }\right)+1$$ which is negative for $1<\lambda$ and the second derivative $$f''(x)=\lambda  e^x$$ is positive, then it is a minimum if $\lambda  >1$. So, since $e^x$ grows much faster than $x$, the function will have another intersection with the $x$ axis.

The second solution has an analytical expression in terms of Lambert function $$x=-\lambda -W\left(-e^{-\lambda } \lambda \right)$$ and its value will be more and more negative when $\lambda$ increases.

For sure, there is a simpler manner of looking at the solution of $f(x)=0$ since it corresponds to the intersection of the two curves $y=e^x$ and $y=1+\frac{x}{\lambda}$